# GregorianCalendar constant date

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

Ok, I want to make my program print out the date: 1/1/2009

But this is what it prints out:

Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2009

From this code

```
GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
public void setStart()
{
    startDate.setLenient(false);
    Date date = new Date(startDate.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

How can I change it so that it only prints out 1/1/2009?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
public void setStart() {
  startDate.setLenient(false); 
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
  df.format(startDate.getDate());
}
```

You're implicitly calling the `toString()` method which is (correctly) printing out the complete contents.

By the way, there is no need to construct a date the way you're doing. Calling `getDate()` on a `Calendar` returns a `Date` object.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the [`Date.toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()) method is being called to display the `String` representation of the [`GregorianCalendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) instance.

What needs to be done is to create a [`DateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) which will produce a `String` representation which is desired. The `DateFormat` object can be used to format a `Date` instance to the desired formatting using the [`format`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) method.

The simplest way to achieve what is desired is to use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class, which has a [constructor which takes a format string](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)) to output the `Date` in a desired form.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Output

```
1/1/2009
```

Comment: for some reason, no matter what month i put, the output of the month is 0. When I do that, I get 1/0/2009