# GregorianCalendar months

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

```
GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/m/yyyy"); 
public void setStart()
{
    startDate.setLenient(false);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(startDate.getTime()));
}
```

When I run this code, I get 1/0/2009. I also get the same thing when I change the months. What is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just FYI, the solution I posted to your original question had uppercase M http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416682/gregoriancalendar-constant-date/1416692#1416692

Comment: yep i didn't notice that it was uppercase. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowercase 'm' is for minute in hour.  You should use the uppercase 'M' instead.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
```

See the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) JavaDoc for more details.